# Does IMAP search work on outlook.com

Tags: email, outlook, imap, outlook.com

I'm new to IMAP.

I'm trying to fetch mails from outlook.com, I have configured outlook.com IMAP settings in my email client. I'm able to connect and get messages from outlook.com.

But when I'm trying to get messages by using search term like

I'm using Java mail packages.

```
IMAPStore store = getStore(serverName, userName, password, port);
IMAPFolder inboxFolder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");

SearchTerm[] searchTerms = new SearchTerm[4];

Address address = new InternetAddress("search_email_address");
SearchTerm toTerm = new RecipientTerm(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
SearchTerm ccTerm = new RecipientTerm(Message.RecipientType.CC, address);
SearchTerm bccTerm = new RecipientTerm(Message.RecipientType.BCC, address);
SearchTerm fromStringTerm = new FromStringTerm(searchEmail);

searchTerms[0] = toTerm;
searchTerms[1] = ccTerm;
searchTerms[2] = bccTerm;
searchTerms[3] = fromStringTerm;

OrTerm orTerms = new OrTerm(searchTerms);

inboxFolder.search(orTerms);
```

I'm trying to search mails using like above search terms in a IMAP folder, but I'm getting zero  mails.

Any API limitations in this or any problems in code, please guide me

Thanks 
Ramesh

Comment: Can you show the IMAP requests and responses that are actually sent and received?

Comment: You have to show the call to Folder.search(), how the arguments to search() are constructed, and ideally also the IMAP command that results.

Comment: @legoscia,@arnt Thanks for your replies, I have updated my code. Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the question "Does IMAP search work on outlook.com" I can say: Yes.

I'm using [imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) to sync from outlook.com to other mailboxes and it works. Behind the scenes imapsync uses IMAP searches.

The IMAP capabilities announced by outlook.com are:

`IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+ AUTH`

Maybe this helps somebody. This could also explain why certain search keywords might or might not work.